# Jenkins pipeline - issue with Branch parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a master Jenkinsfile which will call all the build jobs.
In respective jobs, I have used {BRANCH_SPECIFIER} using gitparameter and few i have not.
The master code

```
if ((params.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' || params.ENVIRONMENT == 'int' && (params.ServiceName == 'Name' || params.ServiceName == 'ALL'))
                stage('stage1') {
                    b = build(job: 'jobname', parameters: [[$class: 'GitParameterValue', name: 'branch', value: branch]], propagate: false).result
                    if(b=='FAILURE'){
                            echo " job failed"
                            currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                        }
```

Child build job

```
branch = "${params.BRANCH_SPECIFIER}"
    WORKING_BRANCH = "${params.BRANCH_SPECIFIER}"
    echo "Branch Specifier is ${branch}"
  stage('Checkout'){
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${branch}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '', url: 'repo.git']]])
    }
```

It is not able to resolve {BRANCH_SPECIFIER} in the individual jobs
Any doc/info will be helpful.

Comment: can you show where you have defined branch if it is supposed to be a variable

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have updated  the question. Let me know if more info is required. I did try with double quotes. Seems making some minor mistake. May be the parameter is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Try it and check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it as normal environment variables . Jenkins passes those parameters as environment variables .

```
branch = "${env.BRANCH_SPECIFIER}"
```

Try using this .

Comment: Thanks, I did something like this and it fixed.